# Why settimeout() sequence has impact on performance?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

There are two similar javascript program A and B.(Test in Chrome  59.0.3071.115 (64bit)).The Program ref to [Scheduling: setTimeout and setInterval](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#splitting-cpu-hungry-tasks)

program A:(run about 5858ms)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let i = 0;
let start = Date.now();

function count() {

  // move the scheduling at the beginning
  if (i < 1e9 - 1e6) {
    setTimeout(count, 0); // schedule the new call
  }

  do {
    i++;
  } while (i % 1e6 != 0);

  if (i == 1e9) {
    alert("Done in " + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
  }

}

count();

</script>
```

program B (run about 11294ms)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

let i = 0;

let start = Date.now();

    function count() {

       // do a piece of the heavy job (*)
      do {
         i++;
      } while (i % 1e6 != 0);


      if (i == 1e9) {
        alert("Done in " + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
      } else {
        setTimeout(count, 0); // schedule the new call (**)
      }


    }

    count();

    </script>
```

Program C(run about nearly A)

```
<script>
    let i = 0;
    let start = Date.now();

    function count() {

      if (i == 1e9) {
        alert("Done in " + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
      } else {
        setTimeout(count, 0); // schedule the new call (**)
      }
    // do a piece of the heavy job (*)
      do {
        i++;
      } while (i % 1e6 != 0);

    }
    count();
</script>
```

I know about javascript is single thread and settimeout just push into queue to be excute after specified delay.Compare two code, I can't understand why Program A is faster than Program B under single thread.

That's what i think [excuteQueue.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFLNE.jpg)

Comment: Because your scripts aren't similar?

Comment: Browsers generally adjust small timeout values (like 0) up to some minimum around 10 or 15ms.

Comment: I have test Program C , just modify a litter with Program B. But C  is obviously faster than B.

Comment: Your A program forgot to declare `i`

Comment: Try to measure how long the work and the idle phases take (sum the time deltas of all work phases and sum the deltas of all idle phases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic difference is:

```
1)sets a timer, does a heavy job
2)does a heavy job, sets a timer
```

As Pointy pointed out a 0ms timer waits always longer then 0ms, so basically this is happening:

```
1)
*sets a timer   |
*do heavy job  |
*                       \/
* timer finishes, next job

2)
*do a heavy job
*sets a timer |
*                      |
*                     \/
* timer finishes, next job
```

As you see, the second yields longer.

Comment: Is there a way to make the | be at the right position? :/

Comment: Is there has new browser's thread push the timer into the excuting queue?

Comment: @chajncey no, in nodejs there would be process.nextTick

Comment: I do not mean that the settimeout is a multi-threaded implementation, I mean the browser has other threads to the settimout function into the javascript engine implementation of the queue. Otherwise settimout function on the front and behind no effect.

Comment: @chauncey no timers dont have to *run* (as code), every computer has *hardware timers* which are utilized for this..

Comment: Can u see my pic I just added.Is that the case?